# address book issue need help fixing it

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-outlook-2007

I was cleaning my address book and didn't notice the tick and got ALL my contacts deleted.

Usually in situation like this I ask one of my friends. But now his contact was also deleted. So how can I restore them? I heard that it's hard to delete something completely, so I still hope.

Answer (score 0):

The "Deleted Items" box doesn't just hold email. If you haven't emptied it yet, you should be able to restore the deleted contacts from there.

A [PC magazine article](http://www.pcmag.com/article2/0,2817,1736274,00.asp) shows something similar.

If your Outlook is on an Exchange server, the server admins may be able to recover them as well, depending on how it's set up.